# Using `qnorm` in R

Tags: r

The `qnorm` function in R finds `A` in `P(X < A)`,

How do I go about at using `qnorm` when I have `P(X >= A)`?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the argument `lower.tail=` and use that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either subtract your probability from 1, or use `lower.tail=FALSE`.

```
> pp <- 0.2
> qnorm(pp)
[1] -0.8416212
> 
> pp <- 0.8
> qnorm(1-pp)
[1] -0.8416212
> qnorm(pp,lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] -0.8416212
```

The second approach I assume is probably a bit more stable numerically if you have very low or very high probabilities. See `?qnorm`.